# CMD - IF-Command

Tags: cmd

What's wrong with this code? When starting it, it's stopping before embeding second connection

```
echo off
if exist \\fistcloud\Data-Private goto Connect
if exist \\secondcloud\Data-Work goto Connect2
goto Ende

:Connect
net use D: \\192.168.1.102\Data-Private /user:user password /persistent:no
goto Ende


:Connect2
net use D: \\192.168.0.2\Data-Work /user:user password /persistent:no
goto Ende

:Ende

exit
```

Comment: Next time **DO** mention your goal. ( that you want both to be connected) we should not guess it.

Comment: Sorry, you'r right. I have two nas syncing together. One stands at home, the other one in my office. If I loggin at home with my computer, i want to autostart-connect with my nas standing at home. If I'm in the office-network I want to connect with the office-nas

Comment: Will only one of them be accessible at a time?

Answer (score 1):

```
:Connect
net use D: \\192.168.1.102\Data-Private /user:user password /persistent:no
goto Ende
```

goto Ende ends the script

use following:

```
echo off
if exist \\fistcloud\Data-Private goto Connect
:next
if exist \\secondcloud\Data-Work goto Connect2
goto Ende

:Connect
net use D: \\192.168.1.102\Data-Private /user:user password /persistent:no
goto next


:Connect2
net use D: \\192.168.0.2\Data-Work /user:user password /persistent:no
goto Ende

:Ende

exit
```

Comment: What's the problem with his code ? it's working on my pc

Comment: It will connect only one or two, but not both

Comment: So there is no problem with his code. I thought that's what he wants. he should have mention that

Comment: no syntactic problems, only this, but I had to think where is the problem :D

Comment: Actually, i have two nas syncing together. One stands at home, the other one in my office. If I loggin at home, i want to connect with my nas standing at home.l If I'm in the office-network I want to connect with the office-nas...

Comment: so what is the problem, yours script should work for it

Answer (score 0):

This should map the the one that is available.

```
@echo off
if exist \\fistcloud\Data-Private net use D: \\192.168.1.102\Data-Private /user:user password /persistent:no
if exist \\secondcloud\Data-Work  net use D: \\192.168.0.2\Data-Work /user:user password /persistent:no
```

Comment: Actually I have to use the same drive letter. It should connect either with my nas at home or with my nas standing in the office...

Comment: Try the above then - only one will succeed at either place.